# How to see/save all rows of an object in Python?

Tags: python

I am following this [tutorial](http://cameo.bio/06-predict-gene-modulation-targets.html) in a package.

As you can see, the second output(result.solutions) has 684 rows × 12 columns.

Questions

How can I save them as a text or CSV file to view all the rows separately? or is there anyway to observe all those rows together on jupyter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question should be in what object the solutions are contained in. From your code, we need to investigate what the result of `DifferentialFVA.run()` is.

```
diffFVA = DifferentialFVA(design_space_model=model,
                          reference_model=reference_model,
                          objective=target,
                          variables=[biomass_rxn],
                          normalize_ranges_by=biomass_rxn,
                          points=10)
result = diffFVA.run(surface_only=True)
```

Looking at the [source code](https://pythonhosted.org/cameo/_modules/cameo/strain_design/deterministic/flux_variability_based.html), the last few lines are

```
total = pandas.concat(collection, ignore_index=True, copy=False)
total.sort_values(['biomass', 'production', 'reaction'], inplace=True)
total.index = total['reaction']
return DifferentialFVAResult(total, self.envelope, self.reference_flux_ranges, self.reference_flux_dist)
```

And

```
class DifferentialFVAResult(StrainDesignMethodResult):
    def __init__(self, solutions, phase_plane, reference_fva, reference_fluxes, *args, **kwargs):
        self.phase_plane = phase_plane
        super(DifferentialFVAResult, self).__init__(self._generate_designs(solutions, reference_fva, reference_fluxes),
                                                    *args, **kwargs)
        self.reference_fva = reference_fva
        self.reference_fluxes = reference_fluxes
        self.solutions = solutions
```

Therefore, to access the solutions you only need to do

```
solutions = result.solutions
```

Which is the same object as `total` from `DifferentialFVA.run()`. And that is just a concatenation of DataFrame objects, which results in another DataFrame. You can simply save that to a file with

```
solutions.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to put so much code, not so related to the final answer which is only the export ;)

Comment: @azro That is true. But I had no knowledge of this package until I saw the question and I wanted to show someone how they could have gone about it.